# Exchange odd and even pages in a pdf file?

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to exchange odd and even pages in a pdf file, e.g. page 1 and page 2 exchange, page 3 and page 4 exchange, ..., assuming the pdf file has even number of pages?

Can it be done using some software e.g. pdftk or LaTeX?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like pdftk's `shuffle` feature will do this. From `man pdftk`:

```
      shuffle [<page ranges>]
             Collates pages from input PDFs to create a new PDF.  Works
             like the cat operation except that it takes one page at a
             time from each page range to assemble the output PDF.
```

The general format for a `[<page range>]` is given as

```
<input PDF handle>[<begin page number>[-<end page number>[<qualifier>]]][<page rotation>]
```

where `qualifier` may be either `even` or `odd`. In the case that you wish to take alternating even and odd pages from the same document until all pages are exhausted, you can omit the `<input PDF handle>` and `<begin page number>-<end page number>` specifiers leaving just

```
pdftk infile.pdf shuffle even odd output outfile.pdf
```

where `infile.pdf` is the file whose pages are to be swapped and `outfile.pdf` is a name for the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qpdf`

```bash
qpdf input.pdf --collate --pages . 1-z:even . 1-z:odd -- output.pdf
```

See [QPDF Documentation](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#page-ranges).