# How can I split each PDF page into two pages, using the command line?

Tags: pdf, image-manipulation

I have a few ebooks scanned from originals. They're formatted so that a single *PDF page* contains two *actual pages*: one on the left, and one on the right.

I want to programmatically split each PDF page into two, so the left 50% of PDF page 1 becomes page 1 and its right becomes page 2, and so on for all the pages.

Does anyone know of a command line utility or script that could help with this?

---

Output from `pdfimages -list -f 1 -l 1 file.pdf`:

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1921  1561  rgb     3   8  jpeg   no       643  0   200   200  200K 2.3%
   1     1 stencil     1     1  -       1   1  image  no   [inline]   0.692     2    -    - 
   1     2 stencil     1     1  -       1   1  image  no   [inline]   0.722 0.650    -    - 
   1     3 stencil     1     1  -       1   1  image  no   [inline]       3     3    -    -
```

Second PDF:

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image     456   625  gray    1   8  jpx    yes      251  0    72    72 11.7K 4.2%
```

Comment: In the past I have successfully used a command line tool "mutool" to extract / slice-up PDF files. It's part of the mupdf package (see: mupdf.com). I don't know if it will work for you in this case however, as far as I understand the above output from pdfimages, your pdf file(s) seem to consist mostly of (or are a wrapper around) a single large JPEG image ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split pages in pdf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should work it needs `pdftk` tool ( and `ghostscript` ).

### A simple case:

**Step One:** Split into individual pages

```
 pdftk clpdf.pdf burst
```

this produces files `pg_0001.pdf, pg_0002.pdf, ... pg_NNNN.pdf`, one for each page.
It also produces `doc_data.txt` which contains page dimensions.

**Step Two:** Create left and right half pages

```
  pw=`cat doc_data.txt  | grep PageMediaDimensions | head -1 | awk '{print $2}'`
  ph=`cat doc_data.txt  | grep PageMediaDimensions | head -1 | awk '{print $3}'`
  w2=$(( pw / 2 ))
  w2px=$(( w2*10 ))
  hpx=$((  ph*10 ))
  for f in  pg_[0-9]*.pdf ; do
   lf=left_$f
   rf=right_$f
   gs -o ${lf} -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g${w2px}x${hpx} -c "<</PageOffset [0 0]>> setpagedevice" -f ${f}
   gs -o ${rf} -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g${w2px}x${hpx} -c "<</PageOffset [-${w2} 0]>> setpagedevice" -f ${f}
  done
```

**Step Three:** Merge left and right in order to produce `newfile.pdf` containing single page .pdf.

```
  ls -1 [lr]*_[0-9]*pdf | sort -n -k3 -t_ > fl
  pdftk `cat fl`  cat output newfile.pdf
```

---

### A more general case:

1. The example above assumes all pages are same size. The `doc_data.txt` file contains size for each split page. If the command

   `grep PageMediaDimensions <doc_data.txt  | sort | uniq | wc -l`

   does not return 1 then the pages have different dimensions and some 
   extra logic is needed in **Step Two**.
2. If the split is not exactly 50:50 then a better formula than `w2=$(( pw / 2 ))`, used in the example above, is needed.

This second example shows how to handle this more general case.

**Step One:** split with `pdftk` as before

**Step Two:** Now create three files that contain the width and height of each pages and a default for the fraction of the split the left page will use.

```
  grep PageMediaDimensions <doc_data.txt | awk '{print $2}'    >   pws.txt
  grep PageMediaDimensions <doc_data.txt | awk '{print $3}'    > phs.txt
  grep PageMediaDimensions <doc_data.txt | awk '{print "0.5"}' > lfrac.txt
```

the file `lfrac.txt` can be hand edited if information is available
for where to split different pages.

**Step Three:** Now create left and right split pages, using the different pages sizes and (if edited) different fractional locations for the split.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3<pws.txt
exec 4<phs.txt
exec 5<lfrac.txt

for f in  pg_[0-9]*.pdf ; do
 read <&3 pwloc
 read <&4 phloc
 read <&5 lfr
 wl=`echo "($lfr)"'*'"$pwloc" | bc -l`;wl=`printf "%0.f" $wl`
 wr=$(( pwloc - wl ))
 lf=left_$f
 rf=right_$f
 hpx=$((  phloc*10 ))
 w2px=$(( wl*10 ))
 gs -o ${lf} -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g${w2px}x${hpx} -c "<</PageOffset [0 0]>> setpagedevice" -f ${f}
 w2px=$(( wr*10 ))
 gs -o ${rf} -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g${w2px}x${hpx} -c "<</PageOffset [-${wl} 0]>> setpagedevice" -f ${f}
done
```

**Step Four:** This is the same merge step as in the previous, simpler, example.

```
  ls -1 [lr]*_[0-9]*pdf | sort -n -k3 -t_ > fl
  pdftk `cat fl`  cat output newfile.pdf
```

Comment: Wow this is impressive, Chris, thank you so much!
I noticed on Fedora, pdftk isn't available, so I used tools from poppler-utils:
`pdfseparate clpdf.pdf pg_%04d.pdf` and `pdfunite $(cat fl) newfile.pdf`

Comment: I just realized that this will double the PDF filesize. It seems each page is  duplicated, just with half the data invisible! I wonder how to fix…

Comment: Thanks for a very comprehensive answer! I believe the height and width are confused so the definitions of `pw` and `ph` should be switched around so `pw` is defined using `awk '{print $3}'` and `ph` uses `awk '{print $2}'`. I have tested this – however, I am using `pfdtk-java` which is a reimplementation of `pdftk` in Java so I would not edit the answer right away.

Comment: This answer does not work for me when the page size is not an integer, so I modified it (and also package it into a script) and post it in another answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You can widen your choice of tools by converting the pdf to PostScript as follows, then using [pstops](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pstops).
I've assumed we start from an A4 portrait page showing two pages as they might have been scanned from an open book, with the spine going horizontally through the middle, like this:

[image: original]

Obviously, you can change the values in the solution below to fit your precise case.

You can convert this pdf to PostScript with `pdf2ps` (which is part of the ghostscript package). Then tool `pstops` from package psutils, can be used to rotate the page right (clockwise) around the bottom left corner, rescale it and move the result up so that only the bottom half covers a whole page:

[image: one page]

A second page can be created from the same original page by a similar rotation, scale, and translation.  The result can be converted back to pdf. A single command can draw each page onto 2 new pages:

```
pdf2ps myfile.pdf out.ps
pstops -p a4 '0R@1.2(1cm,29cm),0R@1.2(-16cm,29cm)' out.ps new.ps
ps2pdf new.ps new.pdf
```

The syntax is explained in the man page. Here we have `R` for rotate right, @1.2 to scale, (x,y) to move the result. The comma (,) produces 2 pages from each original page.

Note that this will double the size of the resulting pdf, since each page is fully drawn twice, even though you only see half of it each time.

Answer (score 6):

You specifically ask for a solution for the command line - probably because you do not want to sit and select every single page.

But if it is acceptable to open every book, then `pdfarranger` will work.

It will not double the size of the PDF-file.

[image: Before splitting]
[image: After splitting]

Answer (score 3):

You want `Libpoppler`, or more precisely the `pdfimages` tool therein. It is free software, will extract the images from the PDF. If the PDF contains scanned images, they are not always oriented correctly, off by a few degrees. If the page contains two images, one for each scanned page, it becomes easy ... if not, you will have to cut them manually (dirty) or try ImageMagick to split them.

http://poppler.freedesktop.org/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages

Taken from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693820/extract-images-from-pdf-without-resampling-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at `imagemagick`:

```
$ convert -resize 1000x1000 /links/www/Salix/pdf/index.pdf a.jpg
$ convert -crop 500x1000+0+0  a.jpg b.jpg
$ convert -crop 500x1000+500+0 a.jpg c.jpg
$ convert c.jpg c.pdf
$ convert b.jpg b.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [PDFjam](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam)  and its daughter script PDFjoin. First crop the left side and save as left.pdf and then crop the right side and save as right.pdf and then merge individual pages of the two files. You can read the examples on the page for inspiration. If that’s too easy for you, you could go the Ghostscript route, but then you’ll have to do some pixel math, external page counting and a final concat etc.

Don’t go the jpg route - you’ll get crazy file bloat and artifact generation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [sejda-console 3](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/releases/tag/v3.2.85):

```
sejda-console splitbyevery -n 2 -f input.pdf --outputPrefix '[BASENAME]_[FILENUMBER###]' --output .
```

`[BASENAME]_[FILENUMBER###]` [means](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/wiki/Customize-output-file-names#filenumber) it will create

```
input_001.pdf
input_002.pdf
...
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617745/5267751 with a small number of modifications. Only works for A4 → A5 paper.

Save the script to a file, then call it as instructed.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
if [[ $# != 3 ]]; then echo "Usage: $0 <input.pdf> <output.pdf> <rotation degrees (0, 90, 180, 270)>"; exit 1; fi

tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)";   trap 'rm -rf "$tmpdir"' EXIT;  olddir="$(pwd)"
cp "$1" "$tmpdir"/input.pdf;  cd "$tmpdir"

qpdf --rotate="$3" input.pdf rotated.pdf
pdfcrop --bbox "0 0 421 595"   --clip --papersize "a5" rotated.pdf left.pdf
pdfcrop --bbox "421 0 842 595" --clip --papersize "a5" rotated.pdf right.pdf
pdftk A=left.pdf B=right.pdf shuffle A B output output.pdf

cd "$olddir"
mv "$tmpdir/out.pdf" "$2"
```

---

### Alternative solution

Modifying [the existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407146/296692), using `pdftk` and `gs`.

This handles non-integer page size (use `python` to calculate the values), and can rotate the page beforehand.

Save the script to a file, then call it as instructed.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
if [[ $# != 3 ]]; then echo "Usage: $0 <input.pdf> <output.pdf> <rotation degrees (0, 90, 180, 270)>"; exit 1; fi

tmpdir="$(mktemp -d)"
trap 'rm -rf "$tmpdir"' EXIT
olddir="$(pwd)"
qpdf --rotate="$3" "$1" "$tmpdir/tmp.pdf"
cd "$tmpdir"

pdftk tmp.pdf burst
grep PageMediaDimensions <doc_data.txt | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ',' > pws.txt
grep PageMediaDimensions <doc_data.txt | awk '{print $3}' | tr -d ',' > phs.txt
grep PageMediaDimensions <doc_data.txt | awk '{print "0.5"}' > lfrac.txt
exec 3<pws.txt
exec 4<phs.txt
exec 5<lfrac.txt
for f in  pg_[0-9]*.pdf ; do
    read <&3 pwloc
    read <&4 phloc
    read <&5 lfr
    wl=$(python -c "print($lfr*$pwloc)")
    wr=$(python -c "print($pwloc-$wl)")
    lf=left_$f
    rf=right_$f
    hpx=$(python -c "print(round($phloc*10))")
    w2px=$(python -c "print(round($wl*10))")
    gs -o ${lf} -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g${w2px}x${hpx} -c "<</PageOffset [0 0]>> setpagedevice" -f ${f}
    w2px=$(python -c "print(round($wr*10))")
    gs -o ${rf} -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -g${w2px}x${hpx} -c "<</PageOffset [-${wl} 0]>> setpagedevice" -f ${f}
done
pdftk $(ls -1 [lr]*_[0-9]*pdf | sort -n -k3 -t_) cat output out.pdf

cd "$olddir"
mv "$tmpdir/out.pdf" "$2"
```

Remark: before pdftk commit https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk/-/commit/d0d4a0b403bc6dceca5f2557f8b643574260e376, the `tr -d ','` is needed to delete the thousand separator, which is usually `,` in common locales.

Answer (score 0):

PDFcreator has a com plugin you may be able to communicate to. But you need the "plus" edition, which is $10 a year.