# Separate high-resolution single-page PDF into multiple pages

Tags: command-line, pdf

How can I separate the following high-resolution single-page PDF into multiple pages (page count is unimportant), so that each page is the size of standard printer paper (8.5"x11"). The map should be zoomed to 200% before it's separated, so that I can see the small details. At 100% resolution lots of details are missed.

https://parks.ny.gov/documents/parks/HarrimanTrailMap.pdf

I've tried some of the solutions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf), even though that question doesn't pertain to this one, but had no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement can be thought of as of tile cropping the original page. I think the following command does what you want:

```
convert -density 288 HarrimanTrailMap.pdf -crop 20% +repage HarrimanTrailMap-tiled.pdf
```

You'll need `imagemagick` and `ghostscript` installed. Also, you may encounter authorisation error when converting PDF files, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52863413/1921546 to resolve that.

If you feel that the resulting tiled PDF has less resolution, increase the `-density` value.

You can specify the `-crop` parameter by considering the number of tiles you want to split the original page into. Here, the original page is split into 5x5 tiles so it is cropped at 1/5=20% horizontally and vertically.

For more information about the command see the following link https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Comment: Tx! That worked nicely. I used the following Ghostscript script to reduce the file from 147mb to 15mb: `wsl ghostscript -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf`