# Splitting a 2up PDF MuTool ‘poster’ style

Tags: bash, shell-script, pdf, image-manipulation

There are many command line tools to convert a 2-up PDF, where two actual pages from a book are combined to form 1 page in a PDF, into a single page format, where 1 PDF page is 1 actual page. The simplest of these is [MuTools poster command](https://www.mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-poster.html). There is an [old discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf) about various methods of doing this.

I am working with reproductions of old documents which are not always split exactly down the center, but up to 5% to the right or left of it. Using the poster tool means that I (and more importantly OCR) can’t read text if it goes over the central split line.

I need a tool that can let each odd page take 5%-10% of the image from the even side and vice versa, to ensure that all text that crosses the line in the original is readable in the PDF. I’ve played about with [pdfjam](https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam), but with little success. If possible I want to avoid using ImageMagick, which is very slow compared to other tools when producing lossless output.

Comment: Have you tried [briss](https://briss.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Looking to run this as part of a shell script that does lots of other stuff, so I need a command  line tool.

Comment: The pdcrop utility that ships with TeXlive lets you specify the exact crop dimensions.