# How to tell convert command to skip a page in pdf?

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf

I want to split a PDF page because it scanned two page at the time and I found this useful [command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12482/split-pages-in-pdf):

```
convert in.pdf -crop 50%x0 +repage -density 400 out.pdf
```

But now I want this command to skip spliting some pages and use them in the final repage result as they are.

Are there any command or a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

1. I hope you set the `-density` correct, so that you do not degrade your image during the re-rasterising. However,  I think `-density 400` should come before `pdf.in` to take an effect.
2. I hope that your pdf file from the corridor scanner is safe, in particular that it is not a Postscript file internally. Also I hope that you have a safe version of `GS` (which is called by IM for pdf/ps/... conversions.) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion),
   [link](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/332928/). (`gs --version` ≥9.24)
3. Anyway, with regard to the previous two points, for the scanner origniated pdf files **I would recommend** to start by `pdfimages` program to extract the scanned pages. Something like

```
   pdfimages -list in.pdf        # show info

   rm temporary*                 # remove temporary files
   rm DOcrop*                    # remove our option files

   pdfimages -all in.pdf temporary    # -all for natural (original) format    
  
   # make your choices; can be done manually by  touch  program
   for x in termporary*; do
        gopen "$x"            # view the file
        echo "File $x: <Enter> for crop, <Ctrl-D> for keep"
        read  &&    touch DOcrop-"$x"
   done
   for x in termporary*; do
        [ -e DOcrop-"$x" ] && mogrify -crop 50%x0 +repage "$x"
   done

   convert temporary*  out.pdf      # some options?
```

4. You can use `convert pdf.in[0-1,7] ...` to use just the specified pages. See 7.
5. You can use tools like `pdftk`, `qpdf`, `pdfselect+pdfunify` to select and/or reorganise the pages
6. For pdfs with vector graphics or text (not good for scanned pags) one can use `pdfcrop` which uses TeX
7. `convert` can have a long [command line](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#option). It seems you will need to use [stack operations](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#stack) if you go this way,
   something like `convert in.pdf[0-9] \( in.pdf[10] -crop ... \) ...`
   to make first ten pages non-changed, and eleventh page cropped. Without `\( \)`, cropping operation would be applied on all preceding pages.
8. IM and GM have scripting tools, which I do not konw.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try it as soon as possible.